# iOS StoryBoard custom font mutable array keeps growing

Tags: ios, storyboard, nsmutablearray

The iOS storyBoard is automatically making a mutable array which keeps growing always with the same, this is it:

```
<customFonts key="customFonts">
    <mutableArray key="Roboto-Medium.ttf">
        <string>Roboto-Medium</string>
        <string>Roboto-Medium</string>
        <string>Roboto-Medium</string>
        ... (lots of more of this things)
        <string>Roboto-Medium</string>
        <string>Roboto-Medium</string>
        <string>Roboto-Medium</string>
    </mutableArray>
```

I think it adds one entry each time I use the font in one of my elements on the storyboard. My question is:

1- Can I simply delete the repetitions without any issue?

2- Why is this mytableArray growing with the same (does it have any purpose)?

3- Is there any way to prevent this array from growing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1- Can I simply delete the repetitions without any issue?

No. That is, you can try, but in a quick test I found that IB simply restored the deleted items in the array. I think it's best not to mess with the storyboard file if you're not sure how your change will affect the file.

> 2- Why is this mutableArray growing with the same (does it have any purpose)?

Hard to say. It only occurs when you use a custom font. I'd guess it's some sort of optimization -- maybe the storyboard doesn't have to look up the proper name for the font if it can find it in the array.

> 3- Is there any way to prevent this array from growing?

Sure. Stop specifying your custom font in the storyboard and instead use `UIAppearance` to specify your custom font for the items affected. I'm not sure why you'd really care, though -- even a thousand copies of the font name aren't going to add much to your app's footprint, and there's a good chance that the same array will be built at runtime anyway.